# При каких случаях экран в android пересоздается

Tags: android

В каких случаях экран пересоздается (Activity) а ViewModel остается?

При:

1. Переворот экрана
2. ..
3. ..?

Comment: Ухх там много всего и почему-то уверен, что не все случаи даже в документации есть. Как минимум смена языка в настройках устройства. Вообще, кроме поворота экрана редко все остальное возникает. Ну и еще часто на слабых устройствах бывает, что система выгружает из памяти даже активности текущего приложения. Можно проэмулировать через настройки разработчика, пункт "Don't keep activities" в самом низу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Активити пересоздается при любом изменении конфигурации:

- смена ориентации
- смена шрифтов/стилей и т.п.
- смена темы

Все что связано с изменением ресурсов на экране вызывает пересоздание активити.

Comment: Официальный список параметров, на изменение которых активность может перезапускаться есть в доке к атрибуту манифеста [`android:configChanges`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element?hl=ru#config)

Comment: Спасибо! т.е. если я показываю toast из ViewModel через LiveData то лучше через SingleLiveData? чтобы каждый раз при смене языка(шрифта и т.д.) не показывать прошлый тост?

Comment: Ну если этот тоаст должен показаться один раз, а не при каждой смене конфигурации то да